# Index beyond bounds error

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsuinteger

I am getting this error:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 556503008 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

Here is where the app crashes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger index = [[Data singleton].annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.pinVC = [[PinViewController alloc]init];
    [self.pinVC setIdentifier:index];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:self.pinVC
                                      animated:YES];
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.pinArray.count;
}
```

I'm new to Objective C, and I don't know why this is happening. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just a few things to begin troubleshooting: show your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.  The number of rows is probably not matching up with whatever you have in your annotations array.  Also, your returned value in `objectAtIndex:` is most likely an object of `NSNumber` and not `NSUInteger`, in which case, you would call `integerValue` on the `NSNumber` object in order to return an integer value.  Finally, what is happening in the `setIdentifier:` method?

Comment: The PinViewController has a identifier property that is a NSUInteger. And the `objectAtIndex:` method returns a `NSUInteger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `pinArray` variable isn't matching up to your call to `objectAtIndex:` on your singleton array.  Assuming `[[Data singleton].annotations` holds the same type of information as your `pinArray` variable, then you might try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSNumber *num = [self.pinArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger index = [num integerValue]; //<-As an aside, observe I converted the number to integer type
    ...
    ...
}
```

The idea is that you are likely returning a higher row count than there are annotation objects in your array, hence the *beyond bounds* error.

Or else you should be doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSNumber *num = [[Data singleton].annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger index = [num integerValue]; //<-As an aside, observe I converted the number to integer type
    ...
    ...
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [Data singleton].annotations.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this line:

```
    NSUInteger index = [[Data singleton].annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`objectAtIndex` returns an object, but you're assigning the result to a primitive (`NSUInteger`, which is a fancy name for an unsigned int). I'm surprised XCode doesn't give you warning at this line. What are you storing in `annotations`?

The error itself is an out of bounds error - although I suppose that means it *could* be the index path itself, as Jeremy suggests in the comments, the fact you're trying to access position 556503008 of the array suggests to me that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

So I realize that I meant to get the index of the object, but I was assigning the object to an NSUInteger, when it is a instance of a custom class. So I just changed that line of code to this:

```
NSUInteger index = indexPath.row;
```